# How to run an isolated Node.js environment inside browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, cors, isomorphic-git

I am trying to use isomorphic-git to perform `git clone` command on browser-side. But due to adhering to the same-origin policy, I cannot send a cross-origin request to our company's GitLab, if no cors-proxy I can use. For security consideration, our company's GitLab team is not willing to alter the CORS config. It seemed that there is no way to clone code from the browser-side. Meanwhile, isomorphic-git provides node-version to clone code, there is no cross-origin problem anymore. But I am not willing to leverage one more node server to do that. Is it possible to launch an isolated Node.js environment inside a browser?

Using isomorphic-git to clone code from GitHub with corsProxy:

```
await git.clone({
  dir,
  corsProxy: 'https://cors.isomorphic-git.org',
  url: 'https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git',
  ref: 'master',
  singleBranch: true,
  depth: 10
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Node is a standalone JS runtime for servers separate from the browser (which has html/css rendering capabilities). Why must you do this browser side?!

Comment: No, you can't run node inside a browser or from a browser unless you have a browser plug-in that can run at the elevated privileges needed to do that and lots of code was already installed locally.  If you understand anything about either the browser execution or security models, this request, as I understand it, seems to make little sense.

Comment: You can always develop a desktop app instead of a website. You know, like how it used to be. There's no CORS problem with Electron.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me the answer is no, because even if you wedged a NodeJS (emulator? environment? thing?) inside the JavaScript thread somehow, when it wanted to `git clone`, it would have to call out to the browser's API. Then you're in the same place: JavaScript still subject to the same-origin policy.

If you *could* manage this, you should look into landing a bug bounty; sounds like a big security flaw :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is small you can use the free cors proxy - https://cors.isomorphic-git.org/ to clone a repo on the browser side.

Usage:

```
git.clone({
    fs,
    http,
    dir,
    corsProxy: 'https://cors.isomorphic-git.org',
    url: 'https://github.com/example.git',
    ref: 'master',
    singleBranch: true,
    depth: 10
});
```

Reference: https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git#cors-support